# Android: how to connect two views with connector line (crooked line) dynamically?

Tags: android, canvas, android-design-library

As per requirement, I want to draw crooked line between two views dynamically (receive from signal/server in list ) in Activity.
In short a connector( crooked line) need to draw to connect between two views. 
With changing value ( list of item values and item names receive from signal/server) views in  left portion change it's position,the crooked line must point to same item in the right portion.

**Left Portion (From)** : `View` represent measurement item value and

**Right Portion (To )** : `TextView` represent the item name.

Please check this image for more details: [image: required]

I checked  [link!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576374/draw-arrow-between-two-listview) and [link2!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961002/create-l-shape-curved-line-with-dynamic-data) in stack overflow but not got the required solution.My question is **how i can connect the list of item value with respective list of item name dynamically??** So,can anyone help me to solve this or any hints or idea??